How to deploy front end & backend apps on same machine with same domain but different ports?
I have two apps one for frontend built using ReactJS and one is for backend built using Django. I have server machine where I have deployed both the apps. Now I want to use Nginx (because of SSL) to host both my application on the same machine with same domain name but the ports are different. I know how to do it for different domains or subdomain but I don't have another domain/subdomain with me right now. So I want to aks how I can achive this in Nginx? For example my FE is using port 4173 & BE is using 8000,I am able to configure Nginx to serve my FE but I am getting this error,  Blocked loading mixed active content because my FE which is httpstrying to connect to backend on port 8000 which is not https.
Here is my nginx config file
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name camfire.pp.ua;

    # Перенаправлення HTTP на HTTPS
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name camfire.pp.ua;

    # Шляхи до сертифікатів SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/camfire.pp.ua/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/camfire.pp.ua/privkey.pem;

    # Проксирування запитів до FrontEnd
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4173;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # Проксирування запитів до BackEnd
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

Any help would be appreciated....

You can achieve this.
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name camfire.pp.ua;

    # Перенаправлення HTTP на HTTPS
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}



server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name camfire.pp.ua;

    # Шляхи до сертифікатів SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/camfire.pp.ua/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/camfire.pp.ua/privkey.pem;

    # Проксирування запитів до BackEnd
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade'
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # Проксирування запитів до FrontEnd
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4173;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade'
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    
}

Ensure you are not passing the port number in your frontend app when querying the backend.
